# \n tag in not printing extra line in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code

```
one.innerHTML += "Today is : " + days[d.getDay()] + "\n";
one.innerHTML += " Current time is : " + d.getHours() + " : " + d.getMinutes() + " : " + d.getSeconds();
```

I'm expecting it to print :

```
Today is : Sunday 
Current time is : 6 : 32 : 34
```

However it prints this :

```
Today is : Sunday Current time is : 6 : 32 : 34
```

Looks like \n is not working here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Learn HTML first. HTML treats sequences of whitespace characters (space, tab, newline) as a single space. If you want to produce a new line in HTML you must use the `<br>` HTML tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in several ways:

**First** 
to render an html element to the dom:

```
var para = document.createElement("br");
one.innerHTML += "Today is : " + days[d.getDay()];
one.appendChild(para);
```

**second**

use Document:

```
one.innerHTML += "Today is : " + days[d.getDay()];
document.write("\n");
```

**The HTML one will render as line breaks for the person viewing the page, the \n just drops the text to the next line in the source (if it's on an HTML page).**

Answer (score 1):

Use [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) tag to break into a new line .

**DEMO**

```js
 var one = document.getElementById("results");
one.innerHTML += "Today is : " + new Date().getDay() + "<br>";
one.innerHTML += " Current time is : " + new Date().getHours() + " : " + new Date().getMinutes() + " : " + new Date().getSeconds();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 
</head>
<body>
<div id="results">
 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use HTML 'br' tag instead of \n. I think it'll work

Answer (score 1):

Don't use \n, Just try this:

```
var string = "this\
is a multi\
line\
string";
```

Just enter a back-slash and keep on trucking!